# Alternative for Appinit_dll in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am hooking to another application process using AppInit_dll, but this hooking is not working in Windows 10 machine.

If I disable secure boot [UEFI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn481258.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it is working as expected.

Can anyone know alternative for AppINIT_dll

Comment: this is by design: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2853424

Comment: The Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit (ACT) may be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Can I hook to the another process without place dll in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows location

Comment: Hi Harry Johnston, Can you tell me more information? I am searching but do not find more information

Comment: We can inject dll using remote thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for dll injection. Once the dll injection is done, you need to run a method infinitely and use another thread for your code to run in parallel.